# "The test statistic is reported as a z..."

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, z-test

I was reading a [neuroimaging paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3646075/pdf/nihms420982.pdf) in which the authors compare the effect of a chemical compound on a measure of brain connectivity. They measure the value of connectivity for each [brain voxel](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/2012/06/21/whats-a-voxel-and-what-can-it-tell-us-a-primer-on-fmri/) under two conditions: with and without the chemical compound being introduced in the body. The authors continue:

> We then computed a one-sample t-test on all the brain voxels. Because
>   of the very large sample (> 220,000 voxels), the test statistic is
>   reported as a z and effect sizes are included.

I don't really understand what is meant by the phrase "the test statistic is reported as a z". Does it mean that with a large number of t-tests, we can interpret the t-statistic values as z-scores? What is the justification of this process?

Is it possible that they do: t-statistic values -> p values -> z-scores? Is this common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The with large degrees of freedom, $\nu$, the distribution of a $t_\nu$ is very close to a standard normal.

The text says "**a** *one sample t-test on* **all** *the brain voxels*", so I assume it's a single t-test across all voxels, with 220000+ df (if it was per-voxel, I'd expect to see "each of" rather than "all"). Even so, it's ambiguous -- if it is one t-test per-voxel, a similar reasoning would apply on the assumption that it's 50 observations per voxel, one per image; many people happily approximate the $t$ by the normal for 49 df.

So while it's still a t-test because the test statistic is a t-statistic, with a t-distribution*, rather than look up a $t_{\nu}$ distribution (for large $\nu$) to compute critical values or p-values, they use z-tables ... which, aside from the extreme tail, will be very close from the exact distribution.

[image]

* as long as the assumptions hold. It's not clear to me why independence would be expected to hold up (under either interpretation above), for example.

I don't think they're converting p-values to z-scores.

Comment: According to your interpretation, they computed only one t-test (with >220000 degrees of freedom), right? Intially I understood that they did a separate t-test for each voxel.

Comment: Since it says "**a** *one sample t-test on* **all** *the brain voxels*". If it was per-voxel, I'd expect to see "each of" rather than "all". I agree that even so, it's still ambiguous. On the other hand, if it is per-voxel, a similar reasoning would apply on the assumption that it's 50 observations per voxel, one per image. I will edit to incorporate the other interpretation.

Comment: I've edited to include both ways of reading it.

Answer (score 1):

It is always convinient to use z-scores instead of t-values. A nice transform is goes like this.
$z=\phi^{-1}(F_{sample size}(t))$. Where $\phi$ and $F_{samplesize}$ are the cummulative distribution of the normal and $t_{samplesize}$.

Comment: In the quote nothing is said about transforming t-values. It seems that they rather threat t-values as Z-values.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the wording that they probably used [*Z*-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test) rather than [*t*-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test).

Comment: I don't think so, as it's clearly stated that they compute one-sample t-tests. To me this seems somehow related to the large number of tests; however, I don't know how.